# Microsoft Remote Desktop - "Started Connecting, Giving Up"

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop

My local machine is a Mac and I ran out of disk space on on my remote machine's "/dev/xvda1" filesystem.

```
% sudo df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            10190104   9321508    747356  93% /
tmpfs                 15701132     27684  15673448   1% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1         913044544  89288740 777352704  11% /local
```

so to make space on my remote machine I did "rm -rf /tmp/" to empty the "/tmp" directory.

Now I am trying to connect to Windows Remote Desktop...

[image: Log In]

And I get a blue screen for a while

[image: Blue Screen]

And then this error message:

[image: Error Message]

I believe for my desktop I am using xrdp with Amazon Linux.

Please help me get my remote desktop working again. I tried Googling the error message and I got this...

https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/731

And then I searched for "xrdp.log" on my remote host:

```
[20180416-17:41:56] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:00] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:03] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:07] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:10] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:17] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:24] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connection problem, giving up
[20180416-17:42:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-17:42:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: some problem
[20180416-17:42:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20180416-17:42:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 16 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:38218)
[20180416-17:47:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.200.170.171:3389)
[20180416-17:47:52] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20180416-17:47:52] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state, terminating listener
[20180416-18:14:54] [INFO ] A connection received from: 10.49.255.195 port 49879
[20180416-18:14:54] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.200.170.171:3389)
[20180416-18:14:54] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
[20180416-18:14:54] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180416-18:14:54] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180416-18:14:54] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 0
[20180416-18:14:54] [INFO ] Non-TLS connection established from 10.49.255.195 port 49879: encrypted with standard RDP security
[20180416-18:14:54] [DEBUG] xrdp_00001be7_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20180416-18:14:54] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20180416-18:14:54] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20180416-18:15:12] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.200.170.171:3389)
[20180416-18:15:12] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20180416-18:15:12] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state, terminating listener
[20180416-18:15:15] [INFO ] A connection received from: 10.49.255.195 port 49880
[20180416-18:15:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.200.170.171:3389)
[20180416-18:15:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
[20180416-18:15:15] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180416-18:15:15] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180416-18:15:15] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 0
[20180416-18:15:16] [INFO ] Non-TLS connection established from 10.49.255.195 port 49880: encrypted with standard RDP security
[20180416-18:15:16] [DEBUG] xrdp_00001ef9_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20180416-18:15:16] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20180416-18:15:16] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20180416-18:15:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20180416-18:15:22] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20180416-18:15:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20180416-18:15:22] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20180416-18:15:22] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20180416-18:15:22] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20180416-18:15:26] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:29] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:33] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:40] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:54] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:15:57] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:01] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:04] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:08] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:11] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:18] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:29] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:32] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:39] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:53] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:16:57] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:00] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:04] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:08] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:11] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:18] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:29] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:32] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:39] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:50] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:53] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:17:57] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:00] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:04] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:07] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:11] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:18] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:28] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:32] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:35] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:39] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:52] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connection problem, giving up
[20180416-18:18:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
[20180416-18:18:52] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: some problem
[20180416-18:18:52] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20180416-18:18:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 16 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:42084)
[20180416-18:19:01] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.200.170.171:3389)
[20180416-18:19:01] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20180416-18:19:01] [ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state, terminating listener
```

And when I searched for "xrdp-sesman.log" I found:

```
% sudo tail -500 /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
[20180228-03:26:02] [INFO ] configuration reloaded, log subsystem restarted
[20180228-16:00:31] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43350
[20180228-16:00:31] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.126:64019 - socket: 12
[20180228-16:00:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180228-17:50:18] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 47400
[20180228-17:50:18] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.126:65278 - socket: 12
[20180228-17:50:18] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180301-20:12:20] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 48658
[20180301-20:12:21] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.126:61763 - socket: 12
[20180301-20:12:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180301-20:24:43] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 49244
[20180301-20:24:43] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.126:61900 - socket: 12
[20180301-20:24:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180305-15:31:51] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 34020
[20180305-15:31:52] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.191:50543 - socket: 12
[20180305-15:31:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180306-15:30:48] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 54240
[20180306-15:30:49] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.165:62797 - socket: 12
[20180306-15:30:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180306-16:43:31] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 33248
[20180306-16:43:31] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.165:63831 - socket: 12
[20180306-16:43:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180306-18:26:27] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43996
[20180306-18:26:27] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.165:64470 - socket: 12
[20180306-18:26:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180306-21:35:28] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 57534
[20180306-21:35:29] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.165:51530 - socket: 12
[20180306-21:35:29] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180307-17:33:51] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 36666
[20180307-17:33:52] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.88.19.247:53893 - socket: 12
[20180307-17:33:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180307-22:33:43] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 51766
[20180307-22:33:44] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.85.48.73:58224 - socket: 12
[20180307-22:33:44] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180308-18:09:58] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 57188
[20180308-18:09:58] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.88.20.166:59078 - socket: 12
[20180308-18:09:58] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180308-19:35:15] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 59708
[20180308-19:35:16] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.85.60.221:52994 - socket: 12
[20180308-19:35:16] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180312-14:16:54] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 41070
[20180312-14:16:55] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.191:62212 - socket: 12
[20180312-14:16:55] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180312-20:09:32] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 59098
[20180312-20:09:35] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180312-20:09:48] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 59102
[20180312-20:09:48] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.88.29.179:51151 - socket: 12
[20180312-20:09:48] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180313-16:30:55] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 40114
[20180313-16:30:57] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180313-16:31:08] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 40126
[20180313-16:31:09] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.88.27.112:59604 - socket: 12
[20180313-16:31:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180314-17:20:15] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 56480
[20180314-17:20:15] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.205:53477 - socket: 12
[20180314-17:20:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180314-19:05:09] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 60834
[20180314-19:05:12] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180314-19:05:23] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 60852
[20180314-19:05:24] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.205:56514 - socket: 12
[20180314-19:05:24] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180316-18:23:24] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 56532
[20180316-18:23:25] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.205:49862 - socket: 12
[20180316-18:23:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180319-15:12:38] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 47290
[20180319-15:12:38] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.197:54961 - socket: 12
[20180319-15:12:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180320-14:37:09] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 48900
[20180320-14:37:10] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.132:59540 - socket: 12
[20180320-14:37:10] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180320-20:52:55] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43384
[20180320-20:52:56] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.132:63821 - socket: 12
[20180320-20:52:56] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180321-14:49:51] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 49580
[20180321-14:49:52] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.137:65059 - socket: 12
[20180321-14:49:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180326-14:06:22] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 58352
[20180326-14:06:22] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:50658 - socket: 12
[20180326-14:06:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180326-14:25:59] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 59596
[20180326-14:25:59] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:51004 - socket: 12
[20180326-14:25:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180330-14:35:24] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43236
[20180330-14:35:24] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:49791 - socket: 12
[20180330-14:35:24] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180330-14:36:24] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43264
[20180330-14:36:24] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:49801 - socket: 12
[20180330-14:36:24] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180330-14:55:52] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43742
[20180330-14:55:52] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:49880 - socket: 12
[20180330-14:55:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180330-14:59:08] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43820
[20180330-14:59:08] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:49893 - socket: 12
[20180330-14:59:08] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180330-15:06:32] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 45546
[20180330-15:06:33] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:49943 - socket: 12
[20180330-15:06:33] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180330-17:08:35] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 49972
[20180330-17:08:36] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.195:50024 - socket: 12
[20180330-17:08:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180402-14:15:59] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 46452
[20180402-14:15:59] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.189:65333 - socket: 12
[20180402-14:15:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180403-15:31:13] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 43990
[20180403-15:31:16] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180403-15:31:43] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 44012
[20180403-15:31:44] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.189:59291 - socket: 12
[20180403-15:31:44] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180403-19:16:11] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 57778
[20180403-19:16:11] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.189:62463 - socket: 12
[20180403-19:16:11] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180403-19:16:12] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 11155, ip 10.49.255.225:58862 - socket: 12
[20180403-19:16:27] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 57790
[20180403-19:16:27] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username reedjohn, ip 10.49.255.189:62519 - socket: 12
[20180403-19:16:27] [INFO ] starting X11rdp session...
[20180403-19:16:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20180403-19:16:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20180403-19:16:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20180403-19:16:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180403-19:16:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180403-19:16:27] [INFO ] X11rdp :10 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -bs -nolisten tcp -uds -once -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -dpi 96  
[20180403-19:16:28] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=18625 - wmpid=18624
[20180406-17:12:13] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 33272
[20180406-17:12:13] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.189:58895 - socket: 12
[20180406-17:12:13] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180406-18:55:02] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 39004
[20180406-18:55:03] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.189:63328 - socket: 12
[20180406-18:55:03] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180408-20:43:10] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 36142
[20180408-20:43:11] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.50.75.171:57892 - socket: 12
[20180408-20:43:11] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180409-14:12:42] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 35454
[20180409-14:12:43] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.184:61523 - socket: 12
[20180409-14:12:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180409-19:54:58] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 58012
[20180409-19:54:58] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.184:62480 - socket: 12
[20180409-19:54:58] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180409-20:45:00] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 32998
[20180409-20:45:01] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.184:50439 - socket: 12
[20180409-20:45:01] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180409-21:18:22] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 35008
[20180409-21:18:22] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.184:52162 - socket: 12
[20180409-21:18:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180409-21:35:14] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 36140
[20180409-21:35:15] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.184:54416 - socket: 12
[20180409-21:35:15] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180411-14:16:13] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 53052
[20180411-14:16:13] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.184:54094 - socket: 12
[20180411-14:16:13] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180411-14:16:14] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 18623, ip 10.49.255.189:62519 - socket: 12
[20180411-14:16:31] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 53062
[20180411-14:16:31] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username reedjohn, ip 10.49.255.184:54108 - socket: 12
[20180411-14:16:31] [INFO ] starting X11rdp session...
[20180411-14:16:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20180411-14:16:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20180411-14:16:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20180411-14:16:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180411-14:16:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180411-14:16:31] [INFO ] X11rdp :10 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24 -bs -nolisten tcp -uds -once -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -dpi 96  
[20180411-14:16:31] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=25713 - wmpid=25712
[20180411-14:59:37] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 37928
[20180411-14:59:38] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.184:56470 - socket: 12
[20180411-14:59:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180411-16:42:32] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 49186
[20180411-16:42:33] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.184:59057 - socket: 12
[20180411-16:42:33] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180411-20:06:56] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 37492
[20180411-20:06:57] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.184:55146 - socket: 12
[20180411-20:06:57] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180412-17:04:47] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 47836
[20180412-17:04:47] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.184:64198 - socket: 12
[20180412-17:04:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180413-14:35:25] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 33180
[20180413-14:35:25] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.130:52046 - socket: 12
[20180413-14:35:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-14:31:13] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 46130
[20180416-14:31:14] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.195:64664 - socket: 12
[20180416-14:31:14] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-16:57:21] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 33718
[20180416-16:57:22] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.195:51170 - socket: 12
[20180416-16:57:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-17:05:51] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 34606
[20180416-17:05:51] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.195:51348 - socket: 12
[20180416-17:05:51] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-17:28:17] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 37096
[20180416-17:28:18] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.195:51616 - socket: 12
[20180416-17:28:18] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-17:38:39] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 38188
[20180416-17:38:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-17:38:57] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 38218
[20180416-17:38:57] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.195:49351 - socket: 12
[20180416-17:38:57] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180416-18:15:22] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 42084
[20180416-18:15:22] [INFO ] ++ reconnected session: username reedjohn, display :10.0, session_pid 25711, ip 10.49.255.195:49880 - socket: 12
[20180416-18:15:22] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
```

xrdp.ini:

```
% sudo cat /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true
; tcp port to listen
port=3389
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=rdp
; minimum security level allowed for client
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high
; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=
; specify whether SSLv3 should be disabled
#disableSSLv3=true
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=
```

[Trimmed]

Comment: I'm a relatively inexperienced user on this site so if this question is not on the right stack exchange site just let me know.

Comment: Also, if I could get some help/advice with the disk space issue that would be ideal.

Comment: I do have to ask the common questions: Is the username and pw correct as well as ip address and ports? Are the ports forwarded correctly on the destination device? Have you ever been able to connect to it before?

Comment: @EricF Yes, the username and password are correct. If I enter them incorrect I get a different error message. This was working previously.

Comment: What changed between when it was working previously and now?

Comment: `rm -rf /tmp/` This command would actually delete the /tmp directory. See if you still have a /tmp directory and that it has the correct permissions.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but under WSL2/Ubunto, WSL2/Debian and WSL2/Kali,,, ?did you solved it??

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is because there's already a gnome session of the account running locally in the remote machine. I change an account and remote desktop works successfully. Then I kill the local gnome session of the previous account. This time I can login with that account.

Comment: We’re happy that you solved ***your*** problem, but it seems unlikely that the above is relevant to ***this*** question.

Comment: @Scott I had the same log, searched for solution, found this question, then solved my problem with the help of others. I registered the stackexchange account and wrote this answer for people who also searched for solution and found this question, not for the asker who asked this question several months ago (and perhaps had already got his solution), and not for someone who made conclusion arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was searching in forums and many solutions were related to reinstalling XRDP. I connected to the computer via SSH (putty) and I realized that the disk was completely full, I performed a debugging of files and it was solved, after that I could connect via remote desktop.